# Why does the charge density at the centre of a nucleus decrease with increasing mass number?

Tags: nuclear-physics, charge, atomic-physics

I have been learning about the Woods-Saxon approximation for charge distribution in the nucleus; it is given by
$$\rho_{ch}(r)=\frac{\rho_{ch}^0}{1+e^{(r-a)/b}}$$
The value of $\rho_{ch}^0$ decreases with increasing mass number *A*, but it is not immediately clear to me why; the distribution *is* subject to a normalisation condition, but it is
$$\int \rho_{ch}(\textbf{r}) \text{d}^3\textbf{r}=Ze$$
so it is not that the charge distribution is normalised by dividing by the total charge of the nucleus, as I initially thought. Is there some physical explanation for why $\rho_{ch}^0$ decreases with mass number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For light nuclei, up to, say, neon ($z=10$) the numbers of neutrons and protons in the stable isotopes are roughly equal. As *z* increases the ratio of neutrons to protons increases, reaching about 1.5 for lead ($z=82$).

Treating the nucleons in nuclei naively as close-packed spheres of equal radius, the nuclear volume will be proportional to $A=Z+N$, whereas the charge is proportional to $z$. The mean nuclear charge density is therefore proportional to $\frac ZA =\frac1{1+\tfrac NZ}$, so as $Z$ increases and $\frac NZ$ increases, the nuclear charge density decreases.

Comment: Probably "mean charge density", not "mean nuclear density".

Comment: I see! Thank you! <3

Comment: @akhmeteli Many thanks: an accidental omission, now corrected.